# Approximate level set.

Tags: approximation, gradient-descent

I have this ill-posed objective function $\min_{z}f(z)=\|1-k(z)\|$, where $z$ is two dimensional points such that $z_2+\sigma=z_1^2+\sigma$. Based on the assumption that, the underlying manifold of $z$ is one of the level set of $f(z)$. I am approximate this contour by find the step that the first stationary point at along opposite gradient direction at that point $(z,f(z))$, and then apply the same step and direction to the 2D point $z$. The result is in the middle layer in the figure 1.
[Here is a sample image. The top surface is a user-defined l2 loss function over points in middle. The thick curve at the bottom is my current approximation results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2UXS.png)

I am looking for an approximation of 2D manifold(which should be a parabola). Can anyone recommend some researches focusing on the problem that finding the best-fit level sets against feasible sets in terms of some norm.

Comment: From the graph it seems like your parabola should be of the form $y = ax^2 + b$ . The problem now is finding the parameters $a$, $b$. You already obtained a set of points $p_n = (x_n, y_n)$ that "should" be on that parabola. Use gradient descent to find $a$ and $b$ that minimize sum over $n$ of $|(a x_n^2 + b) - y_n|$. The approach for general sets is the same, you get a parameter space of your level-set shapes, and find parameters that minimize the summed distance of your points to those shapes. The only difficult part is finding a good distance function between a point and your shapes.

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. I have already centralized the data. So the deepest surface is corresponding to the origin in feasible set. b is not necessary in this case. Thank you so much.